# Force fit column of flexgrid

Tags: vba, vb6, msflexgrid

What is best way to **force fit** the columns of msflexgrid in vb6?
so, that all columns are visible and they **occupies maximum width** of grid!

---

I've tried this code but it does not properly fit last column inside the grid, can anyone suggest what could be problem?

```
Public Sub **FlexGrid_AutoSizeColumns (** ByRef pGrid As MSHFlexGrid, _  
                                ByRef pForm As Form, _  
                                Optional ByVal pIncludeHeaderRows As Boolean = True, _  
                                Optional ByVal pAllowShrink As Boolean = True, _  
                                Optional ByVal pMinCol As Long = 0, _  
                                Optional ByVal pMaxCol As Long = -1, _  
                                Optional ByVal pBorderSize As Long = 8, _  
Optional fitToScreen As Boolean = False **)**  

Dim lngMinCol As Long, lngMaxCol As Long, lngCurrRow As Long  
Dim lngMinRow As Long, lngMaxRow As Long, lngCurrCol As Long  
Dim lngMaxWidth As Long, lngCurrWidth As Long  
Dim fntFormFont As StdFont  
Dim totalWidth As Integer  
totalWidth = 0  

Set fntFormFont = New StdFont  
Call CopyFont(pForm.Font, fntFormFont)  

Call CopyFont(pGrid.Font, pForm.Font)  

    With pGrid  
        lngMinCol = pMinCol  
        lngMaxCol = IIf(pMaxCol = -1, .Cols - 1, pMaxCol)  
        lngMinRow = IIf(pIncludeHeaderRows, 0, .FixedRows)  
        lngMaxRow = .Rows - 1  

        For lngCurrCol = lngMinCol To lngMaxCol  
            lngMaxWidth = IIf(pAllowShrink, 0, pForm.ScaleX(.ColWidth(lngCurrCol), vbTwips, pForm.ScaleMode))  

            For lngCurrRow = lngMinRow To lngMaxRow   '..find widest text (in scalemode of the form)
                lngCurrWidth = pForm.TextWidth(Trim(.TextMatrix(lngCurrRow, lngCurrCol)))
                If lngMaxWidth < lngCurrWidth Then lngMaxWidth = lngCurrWidth
            Next lngCurrRow

           lngMaxWidth = pForm.ScaleX(lngMaxWidth, pForm.ScaleMode, vbTwips)
           .ColWidth(lngCurrCol) = lngMaxWidth + (pBorderSize * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX)
           totalWidth = .ColWidth(lngCurrCol) + totalWidth

       Next lngCurrCol
   End With

Call CopyFont(fntFormFont, pForm.Font)

    If fitToScreen = True Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim gridWidth As Long
        gridWidth = pGrid.Width
        For i = 0 To pGrid.Cols - 1
            pGrid.ColWidth(i) = Int(gridWidth * pGrid.ColWidth(i) / totalWidth)
        Next
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you show an image of your current msflexgrid ? Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2):

One way I could think is to **resize your columns** (with visibility) to fit into the max width found in a column (text). The function returns either 0 or a double value. As long as the returned max column width is not zero, we may adjust the current grid column width accordingly. If zero then it remains the same.

```
Dim i, j,  as Integer
Dim maxWidth as Double
For i = 0 to MsFlexGrid1.Rows - 1
      For j = 0 to MsFlexGrid1.Cols - 1
             maxWidth = maxColWidth(j)
             If maxWidth > 0 then
                MsFlexGrid.ColWidth(j) = maxWidth
             End If
      Next j
Next i


Private Function maxColWidth(coNum as Integer) as Double
Dim i, Max as Integer
Max = 0
    With MsFlexGrid1
         For i = .FixedRows to .Rows-1
              If TextWidth(.TextMatrix(i, colNum)) > Max Then
                   Max = TextWidth(.TextMatrix(i, colNum))
              End If
         Next i    
         maxColWidth = Max
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: @Vinay, one thing I would like add here, you may do an extra check. **if your chosen `max Width` is smaller than max column width, then you may follow the max column width, else you set column width to chosen max width** ? sounds good? :)

Answer (score 1):

to distribute the remaining space over the columns, divide it by the number of columns and add it to each column

```
'1 form with :
'    1 msflexgrid : name=MSFlexGrid1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intCol As Integer
  'example form and grid configuration
  Move 0, 0, 10000, 5000
  With MSFlexGrid1
    .FixedRows = 0
    .FixedCols = 0
    .Rows = 10
    .Cols = 10
    For intCol = 0 To .Cols - 1
      .ColWidth(intCol) = (intCol + 1) * 107
    Next intCol
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  MSFlexGrid1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_Click()
  DistributeWidth
End Sub

Private Sub DistributeWidth()
  Dim intCol As Integer, intColSel As Integer
  Dim lngWidth As Long
  Dim lngRemaining As Long
  Dim lngExpand As Long
  With MSFlexGrid1
    intColSel = .Col                                          'remember selected column
    .Col = 0                                                  'select first column to ...
    lngWidth = .Width - .CellLeft * 2                         '... take flexgrid-borders into account
    .Col = intColSel                                          'select column again
    lngRemaining = lngWidth - InUse                           'calculate the remaining space
    If lngRemaining > 0 Then
      lngExpand = lngRemaining \ .Cols                        'distribute the remaining space over the columns
      For intCol = 0 To .Cols - 1
        .ColWidth(intCol) = .ColWidth(intCol) + lngExpand
      Next intCol
      lngExpand = lngRemaining Mod .Cols
      .ColWidth(.Cols - 1) = .ColWidth(.Cols - 1) + lngExpand 'since we are working with longs, apply the remaining fraction to the last column
    Else
      'what to do with lack of space? Shrink columns or expand grid or nothing?
    End If
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub

Private Function InUse() As Long
'calculate how much of the gridwidth is already in use by the columns
  Dim intCol As Integer
  Dim lngInUse As Long
  With MSFlexGrid1
    lngInUse = 0
    For intCol = 0 To .Cols - 1
      lngInUse = lngInUse + .ColWidth(intCol)
    Next intCol
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
  InUse = lngInUse
End Function
```

The above example somehow does not always fill the area completely, although i think the logic is correct and i can't see anything missing ...

i guess this gives a similar result to what you have? or is it slightly better?